# Sending Data From C# to Matlab M File and Back

Tags: c#, matlab, communication

I have an interface made in MS Visual Studio using C# on a windows form project. I also have a Matlab m file with a lot of calculations inside. I want the data entered by the user to the interface to be sent to this m-file, compiled in matlab in the background and results returned back to the C# interface.

How should I do this? Or would you suggest alternative ways? I would be very happy if you could guide me thoroughly, as I could not understand how the communications work between these programs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Build a dll in Matlab.  Then use DlImport in c# to define methods in Matlab.

Comment: Actually, Matlab has strong .net interop features. No need to resort to pinvoke I think.